# ion-list does not refresh after $state.go is called

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am learning AngularJS and ionic framework using this tutorial:

http://www.htmlxprs.com/post/12/tutorial-on-using-parse-rest-api-and-ionic-framework-together

Everything works well up until the point when I create a new item in the createTodo state and then call $state.go('todos') to go back to my items list, here is the code for the create Todo Controller:

```
.controller('TodoCreateController', ['$scope', 'Todo', '$state', function($scope, Todo, $state) {
    $scope.todo = {};

    $scope.create = function() {
        Todo.create({content: $scope.todo.content}).success(function(data) {
            $state.go('todos', {}, {reload: true});
        });
    }
}])
```

Here is the code for the item list controller:

```
.controller('TodoListController', ['$scope', 'Todo', '$state', function($scope, Todo) {
    Todo.getAll().success(function(data) {
        $scope.items = data.results;
    });

    $scope.deleteItem = function(item) {
        Todo.delete(item.objectId);
        $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
    };
}])
```

Here are the states configured

```
.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('todos', {
        url: '/todos',
        controller: 'TodoListController',
        templateUrl: 'views/todos.html'
    }).state('createTodo', {
        url: '/todo/new',
        controller: 'TodoCreateController',
        templateUrl: 'views/create-todo.html'
    });
})
```

When the application starts, the method of the TodoListController is invoked thanks to the last line added and the end of the .run method in the main app.js (or at least thats my understanding):

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $state) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

        if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if(window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });

    $state.go('todos');
})
```

My problem is that, as soon as the new item is created and I invoke $state.go('todos') from the TodoCreateController, it takes me back to the item list but the new item is not there and the method of the TodoListController is never invoked, therefore leaving the list outdated.

How can I refresh the list in the 'todos' state after a new item has been created?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a rather elegant solution:

Inside my TodoListController I define an event listener like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('todo:listChanged', function() {
    $scope.updateList();
});
```

then comes the updateList() method

```
$scope.updateList = function() {
    Todo.getAll().success(function(data) {
        $scope.items = data.results;
    });
};
```

And finally in the TodoCreateController I $emit the event upwards as soon as the item is created and right before changing state

```
$scope.create = function() {
    Todo.create({content: $scope.todo.content}).success(function(data) {
        $scope.$emit('todo:listChanged');
        $state.go('todos');
    });
};
```

And voila! The list updates accordingly and I can now use the same event if I delete or update a list item

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered this and similar problems and it turned out that **ionic view caching** often was the reason for not calling the controller code when returning to a cached view.

**Possible Solution**

When separating controller code into *one-time-initialization* and *code running when view is entered*, you typically end with controllers looking like this:

```
// one-time initialization
$scope.updateList = function() {
    Todo.getAll().success(function(data) {
        $scope.items = data.results;
    });
};

$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
    $scope.updateList();
});
```

This should solve your problem without having to trigger events or adding params or data to the route.

**Alternative**

It is possible to disable view caching in different ways:

- add `cache: false` to the state definition
- add `cache-view="false"` to the html `<ion-view ...>`
- disable caching with `$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);` (wouldn't recommend this)

**Pitfall when using Sub-States**

Not in your case, but if editing/creating rows in **Sub-States** (e.g. states `todo` for the list and `todo.create` for creating a new todo), there is an additional problem coming from ui-router:

When navigating from `todo.create` to state `todo`, your super-state `todo` won't be "executed", because you're already in this state when coming from `todo.create`. This is a common problem and can be solved by one of the more complicated solutions provided in other answers to this post.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

In your config add:

```
$stateProvider.state('todos', {
    url: '/todos',
    controller: 'TodoListController',
    templateUrl: 'views/todos.html',
    params : {
        updated : false
    }
})
```

Read about params with ui-router [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#name)

Then in your $state.go of your create todo I would change it to this:

```
$scope.create = function() {
    Todo.create({content: $scope.todo.content}).success(function(data) {
        $state.go('todos', {updated: true});
    });
}
```

In your todo controller I would add this

```
if($stateParams.updated == true){
    Todo.getAll().success(function(data) {
        $scope.items = data.results;
    });
    $stateParams.updated = false;
}
```

This way rather than counting on the reload to run the function you are explicitly looking for a value that will trigger the reload.  You can also do the same thing using the `data` object rather than the `params` object and set/retrieve values via:

```
$state.get('createTodo').data.updated = true;
if($state.current.data.updated == true);
```

Hope this helps!

**Another Thought**

add a state change listener to the mix:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if(fromState.name === 'createTodo' && toParams.updated == true){
        Todo.getAll().success(function(data) {
            $scope.items = data.results;
        });
        $stateParams.updated = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jacob, but all of the suggestions assume that the code inside the TodoListController will execute after a new item has been added. But the problem remains. when I call $state.go() inside the TodoCreateController, the state changes but the code inside TodoListController is **not executed** and I don't know why

Comment: Putting the code inside the rootScope.on statechangesuccess will invoke the code. Try it out and let me know

Comment: I does indeed but the code is called like 3 times. In any case, your suggestion gave me an idea that worked well. Thanks a lot for your feedback

Answer (score 2):

This did the trick for me:

```
$state.transitionTo('new-state', $state.$current.params, {reload: true});
```

Comment: Thanks! Works for me too.

Comment: Gives a bad UX effect i.e. feels like a page refresh.